# Joining like events from a file

Tags: python, file, concatenation

I'm curious on how I would go about joining like events from a file and have them report as one event.

Example:

The file includes:

```
Testforthis1
Testforthis2
Testforthat1
Testforthat2
```

How would I go about combining like titled events so they report as Testforthis and Testforthat

Thanks.

Comment: the file is currently a .txt, I'm sure I could convert it if that makes certain things easier

Comment: I bet `itertools.groupby` would be useful here.

Comment: You need to define the rules for joining first. `like events` can be vastly different things in different settings.

Comment: The rules would be Testforthis* and Testforthat*, as to include everything that starts with that particular string.